# My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath

Tags: vb.net

I have two projects (see image). I set my start-up form in "Project 2" but whenever i'm in the module 1 in the "Project 1" then I type **My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath**, the path gives me the path of "Project 2" which is wrong. I want to access the location path of my module in the "Project 1", how?

[>> WRONG PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF1QI.png)

Cheers...

Comment: ` My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath` will always points to the debug folder

Comment: yeah, that is the equivalent of app.path in vb6.. how can i access just only the path of the project? Im just noobie in VB.NET. THANKS SIR UNLUCKY

Comment: @MrYoso If your project1 will be compiled as DLL and Project2 is the EXE, may be this link could be of some help to you [Project Folder Path In Referenced Dll](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/325912-project-folder-path-in-referenced-dll/) on DreamInCode. Also check [GetAssemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies(v=vs.100).aspx) and [LoadedAssemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.assemblyinfo.loadedassemblies(v=vs.100).aspx) on MSDN

Comment: That makes no sense.  When you deploy that compiled EXE to another machine, what would "the project folder" even mean?

Comment: @jmcihinney dude,  I've been browsing through questions and I've noticed that you've replied to several of the,  which of course is good,  but your general tone seems a bit  confrontational.  People are here asking questions be a use they don't know something and maybe quite inexperienced programmers.  Posting comments like 'that makes no sense'  and 'oh my god'  isn't going to make them feel welcome. Probably the best way to compose an answer would be to avoid inflammatory phrases and word it in a business like or even friendly manner.  Just saying.  I know everyone has bad days.  I hope that

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, and of course to @Sir David :) :salute: , I just need a suggestion, like this... "If I were you Mr. Yoso, i'm gonna blah blah blah.. something like that.." What would you do if you were in my position?

Comment: The main problem was, I have 2 folders named "DATA" in the two projects. It contains all stylesheets that will use for the entire system. Of course, I need the path of those two folders in my projects, right? That's why I'm asking how to get that paths because in VB6, it is just APP.PATH + FOLDER NAME which is "DATA" then VIOLA, you've already those paths while in VB.NET is really different, that's why i'm asking what is your solution to this? Thanks fellow Stackoverflowers. =))

Comment: @haraman, Hi idol, I read the link you sent specially the project folder path. It is same as My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, meaning "Application.StartupPath"  =  "My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath",  thanks, any suggestions?

Comment: @MrYoso Application.StartupPath and My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath may NOT always be same, particularly in case of ClickOnce deployment. Their FileIOPermission enumerations are different too.

Comment: @MrYoso And regarding your question formulation, in order to get close answers to you questions try to mention your requirements in the main question itself and not in the comments later such as need to access "DATA" sub folder in your application folder

Comment: @haraman, thanks men, I appreciate your answer to my question.. and some advices. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is to answer my question about the current path or directory of my project. 
I use the REPLACE function to remove the "\bin\Debug\" part like this:

```vb
Dim path As String
path = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
Dim path1 As String = path.Replace("\bin\Debug", "\")
```